# Why do sub-menu items not appear on front page, but work on other pages?

Tags: routes

I have added a link to a Panels page in my main menu.  Beneath that link are items which link to a couple of Webform pages and a Basic page.

On the home page, the sub-items do not appear beneath the heading, but on all other pages, they show up just fine. If I look at Structure->Menus->Main menu, everything is set up correctly. I have cleared caches multiple times, to no avail. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "Every other page", are all the "other" pages that you refer to children of the panels page? I suspect your problem could be resolved by ticking the "Show as expanded" checkbox on that menu item. But it could be any number of things including your theme.

Comment: No, by "other pages" I meant, "not the front page." I did find the "Show as expanded" checkbox, which I had not seen before, and it did indeed solve the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Just ran into the same problem. You should publish this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I suspect your problem could be resolved by ticking the "Show as expanded" checkbox on that menu item.

This worked for me. Thanks, Adam!

Comment: this solved my problem, but i do not know why :)

Comment: It is weird that it was not necessary for pages except the home page